# How to generate a new number for each loops?

Tags: java, loops, random, while-loop, generate

```
  System.out.println("Problem 11:");
  int randomTotal = 0;
  int number1;
  int counter1 = 0;

  number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10) + 1;

  while (counter1 <= 9)
  {
     randomTotal += number1;
     counter1++;
     if (number1 == 5)
        break;
   }
  System.out.println(randomTotal);
```

When the problem loops it reuses the same random number, how do I generate a new random number got each loop? I am trying to add 10 random numbers together and when the random number is 5 I want to create a break and stop the numbers it already has. So if it is 6, 7, 8, 5, it will add those together and not add any more numbers. Also is there a way to display what the random numbers are? Thank you

Comment: It's so simple, I suggest reading some (a lot of) Java [tutorials](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/721604/programming-with-java-for-beginners) and try to solve it yourself before asking.

Comment: [How much effort is expected of StackOverflow users?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users)

Comment: @user202729 thanksfor a link ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what randomNumers is but this might do the trick:

```
number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10) + 1;

  while (counter1 <= 9)
  {
     System.out.println("random number in while iteration " + counter1 + " equals: " + number1);

     randomTotal += number1;
     counter1++;
     if (number1 == 5)
        break;
     number1 = randomNumbers.nextInt(10) + 1;
 }
```

So you can put System.out.println wherever You like. And it always used same number, because you assigned variable only once and used it every loop iteration instead of changing it each loop iteration.

Comment: I suggest not answering such bad questions (bad, as evidenced by the vote tally) because it encourages bad questions to the site.

Comment: Seems fair I guess. But I thought It's better to give an answer and so he actually receives an answer and perhaps learns something. Do You think I should delete the answer?

Comment: [Reading meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/281793/stance-on-answering-bad-questions), wait a minute.

Comment: As I don't think the answer is bad(I wrote it so obviously I don't :D) the top answer from the topic you linked suggests editing the question, making it  good. Not sure how to do that though.